# Does react-firebase-hooks support the latest version of firebase?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to set up basic authentication in my Next App with Firebase and firebase hooks.

Whenever I pass the firebase.auth() instance to the hook

```jsx
import {useAuthState} from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth'
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {

  const [user] = useAuthState(firebase.auth())

  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}}
```

I receive the error below

```js
Argument of type 'firebase.default.auth.Auth' is not assignable to parameter of type '
import("[PROJECT_PATH]/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth-public").Auth'.
  Property 'beforeAuthStateChanged' is missing in type 'firebase.default.auth.Auth' 
but required in type [PROJECT_PATH]/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth-public").Auth
```

My guess is that `react-firebase-hooks` needs an update so as of now I'm going to typecast `as any` but if anyone has deeper insight I'd love to hear

Answer (score 2):

`firebase.auth()` gets the Auth service. Instead, what you should pass is the Auth instance. something like this

```js
// in client.ts
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
const firebaseConfig = {...}
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
export const auth = getAuth(app);
```

```js
import { auth } from "../client";
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {

  const [user] = useAuthState(auth)

  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use following format to have a loading and error variable:

```
const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);
```

This helps to understand when to use user.